# If two radio button checked, add css to div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checked

There are two radio buttons separately. Have different name values. I'm trying to add a css to the div element when both are "checked".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="nameone"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(".calculate-total").css("display","block")
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nameone" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nametwo" /> Namtwo radio
</label>

<div class="calculate-total" style="display:none;">If two radio checked both, this div will be visible.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second `if` condition like you do for the `input[name="nameone"]`:

```js
function showDiv() {
  if ($('input[name="nameone"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="nametwo"]').is(":checked")) {
    $(".calculate-total").css("display", "block")
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="nameone"], input[name="nametwo"]').click(function() {
    showDiv();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="nameone" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nametwo" /> Namtwo radio
</label>

<div class="calculate-total" style="display:none;">If two radio checked both, this div will be visible.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check if both of them are checked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="nameone"], input[name="nametwo"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[name="nameone"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="nametwo"]').is(":checked")){
            $(".calculate-total").css("display","block")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking if the first radio input is clicked (checked), that's why you the div is showing when you click on the first radio input. You should listen/check for both. If both are clicked (checked). Then that's when you want to do something. You can use the && to get the job done

```js
function showDiv() {
  if ($('input[name="nameone"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="nametwo"]').is(":checked")) {
    $(".calculate-total").css("display", "block")
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="nameone"], input[name="nametwo"]').click(function() {
    showDiv();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="nameone" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nametwo" /> Namtwo radio
</label>

<div class="calculate-total" style="display:none;">If two radio checked both, this div will be visible.</div>
```

Comment: Looks really really really close to my answer :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if all radio buttons are checked and based on this check you can toggle the visibility of the block.

I added a class to the radiobuttons you want to check. And only if the length of all radiobuttons is equal to the checked onces i show the calculate-total div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($('.check-it').filter(':checked').length === $('.check-it').length) {
      $(".calculate-total").css("display", "block")
    } else {
      $(".calculate-total").css("display", "none")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nameone" class="check-it" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nameone" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nametwo" class="check-it" /> Namtwo radio
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="nametwo" /> Namtwo radio
</label>

<div class="calculate-total" style="display:none;">If two radio checked both, this div will be visible.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for both radio buttons and check for both each time:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
         if($('input[name="nameone"]').is(":checked") && $('input[name="nametwo"]').is(":checked")){
              $(".calculate-total").css("display","block")
         }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <input type="radio" name="nameone" /> Nameone radio
</label>
<br><br>
<label>
      <input type="radio" name="nametwo" /> Namtwo radio
</label>
<div class="calculate-total" style="display:none;">If two radio checked both, this div will be visible.</div>
```